# How do you read a Google Search URL?

Tags: search

I want to write a TextExpander snippet that will let me search between two arbitrary dates. To do that I need to be able to read the search URL, but I can't find a good guide online. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: A bit circular.  I like it.  ....no Google results on that one?